# Charge redistribution DAC CMOS body diode leakage

Tags: adc, cmos

I am working on a charge redistribution DAC + sample & hold circuit for an SAR ADC according to the image below:
[image]

I have the switches implemented as PMOS/NMOS transistors.

In the sample state, SA is closed and SB is tied to ground, which makes the capacitors charge to the input voltage Vin. Then, in the hold state, SA opens first, then SB is opened (bus B is left floating), the switches S0' to S4 are switched to ground and lastly SB is switched to Vref = 1.8V. The output bus (Vc, at comparator positive terminal) is now equal to -Vin. For example, if Vin = 1V then at this stage, Vout would be -1V with respect to ground.

My problem is, that since the voltage on the capacitors is negative at this point, the capacitors get discharged through the parasitic body diode of SA, which is implemented as an NMOS. Essentially, there is no way to open the NMOS switch SA since the body diode always provides a path from ground to the more-negative output bus.

I could split the supply voltage and make source of SA negative voltage with respect to ground which would eliminate the issue, but this would cut the dynamic range in half. Is there a different way to resolve this issue?